# In my new MediaWiki installation, subpages are not being recognized

Tags: mediawiki

Attempting to transclude a subpage from its parent page via its relative name `{{/subpageName}}` causes the parent page to display a red link to a page literally named `/subpageName`, when it should be displaying the contents of `parentpageName/subpageName`.

Similarly, when navigating directly to a subpage, the sub-header that normally displays an automatic link to the current page's parent is always missing (the sub-header is usually displayed in the `#contentSub` element at the top of the page, directly beneath the page title).

It seems as though MediaWiki isn't recognizing forward slashes as indicative of a directory structure. The MediaWiki documentation seems to indicate that subpages are a default behavior and that no extensions or special settings are required (https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Template#Relative_name_for_transcluded_page).

I'm using MediaWiki 1.28 via the Bitnami 1.28 Turnkey MediaWiki package installed on Windows 10. I've tried purging the cache and disabling all MediaWiki extensions (neither made subpages work).

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Probably [`$wgNamespacesWithSubpages`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespacesWithSubpages) not set right?

Comment: @Tgr Yes! That was it, thank you! If you want to post this as an answer I'll choose it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all MediaWiki namespaces are subpage-aware (because they need to handle titles with slashes in them - it would be weird, if, say, the Wikipedia entry on [AC/DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC/DC) would link to AC as a parent page). You can use [`$wgNamespacesWithSubpages`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgNamespacesWithSubpages) to configure which ones should be. So if you want `{{/subpageName}}` to work in the main namespace, you can set

```
$wgNamespacesWithSubpages[NS_MAIN] = true;
```

in your `LocalSettings.php`.

Comment: For me this was `$wgNamespacesWithSubpages = [NS_TALK => true, NS_USER => true, NS_USER_TALK => true];`
... located in mediawiki/htdocs/includes/DefaultSettings.php. Thanks!!

Comment: No, you should use [LocalSettings](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php). DefaultSettings will be overwritten when you update MediaWiki (plus it contains every single setting so it's harder to keep track of what you have changed).

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't see any existing setting for this in LocalSettings.php so I went searching. I guess it can be added if it's not there yet. PS. I also wanted to point out the syntax difference in mine (multiple namespaces in one statement via `=>` ) but I'm guessing either will work.

Comment: `$arr['key'] = $val` only changes that one key. `$arr = [ 'key' => $val ]` overrides the array (any other keys will be lost) which is not something you want (DefaultSettings can get away with it because it is the code that initializes the variable, and is called early enough that nothing else could have set it before). You can do something like `$arr = [ 'key' => $val ] + $arr` or `$arr = array_merge( $arr, [ 'key' => $val ] )` but neither looks very nice IMO.